# Form is not being centered and the button getting out of the border in firefox and edge

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble to align the form and texts above form in the center. Getting strange behavior. If I zoom 100%, then send button goes out of the box in all browsers. But, the button stays in the box in above or under 100%. Also, inline form elements break. Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Here is the link:

http://107.180.106.101:8081/reservations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
#content-container{
    min-height: 370px;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

instead of

```
#content-container{
    min-height: 370px;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

to center the whole content

Comment: Thank very much. It solved the form alignment issue.